# Question on framed bordism classes definition

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I was reading recently about cobordism, and in specific about the Thom-Pontraygin theorem which states $\pi_{k}(S^n)$ is isomorphic to the cobordism classes of framed $n$-manifolds in $R^k$.

In relation to this, I also found mention of a group of framed bordism class, which I found to be denoted by $\Omega_i^{fr}$. However, I cannot seem to figure out what this means. I know a framing is some trivial bundle, but how big is the bundle (what dimension) if we talk about the framing of an $i$-manifold.

A definition of $\Omega_i^{fr}$ and an explanation of what it means would be much appreciated

Comment: To clarify some of my confusion, doesn't a framing require an embedding of the manifolds and a trivialization of a normal bundle, but how does this make sense for abstract manifolds?

Comment: There are two things people mean by a framing. One of them is a choice of trivialization of the tangent bundle. The other is a choice of trivialization of the *stable* normal bundle, or equivalently of the stable tangent bundle (which does not depend on a choice of embedding). Framed bordism uses the latter definition (same as complex bordism, which is not about complex structures on the tangent bundle but about complex structures on the stable normal bundle).

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, but now I guess I have a question about stable normal bundles. Doesn't the dimension of this bundle depend on the $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is embedded into. I understand for large enough $n$ the normal bundles are all isotopic, but the normal bundle of a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is different from that when it is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, does this mean one can compute $\Omega_i^{fr}$ as $\Omega_{i;\mathbb{R}^k}^{fr}$ for $k\gg i$?

Comment: A stable bundle doesn't have a notion of dimension. (Recall that "stable" means we identify a bundle $V$ and $V \oplus \mathbb{R}^k$ for all $k$.)